# Basic vectors question..

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If a car was traveling with velocity v, then 5 minutes later its velocity was 1.1v and then 10 minutes later its velocity was -v. What happened?

Am I right in thinking that the car sped up and then drove back or reversed?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "what happened"? Are you just looking for the concavity of the velocity, or are you looking for a specific function to express it?

Comment: Or perhaps it was accelerating toward a train along the tracks until it was hit and then carried along for a ways? This is rather vague, as it stands.

Comment: The car could be on an oval racing track, with two parallel straightaways (there is a mention of vectors in the OP). So the velocity need never be $0$.

Comment: Just looking at velocity with this question..

Comment: Is this a vector question or not? Velocity is a vector quantity, depending on how many directions the motion describes. If your question is not about vectors, you should remove it from the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In physics problems, we usually, first, assume a coordinate system and get a "Positive" direction. therefore, if velocity negated in our presume coordinate sys., it means that the object turns back. it can be observed from the definition of velocity:
$$v=\frac{x_2-x_1}{t}$$
in which we can take $x_1$ as much close to $x_2$ as we need.
then, if $x_2<x_1$ (turning back!) velocity will be negated.
Summary of all: The object stars to travel, speed up, turns back!

By "vector thinking" -v is exactly the vector which has the length of v but in the opposite direction of it.

Answer (score 3):

Given that by the laws of Newtonian physics, the velocity function must be continuous, so at some point between the $5$ minute and $10$ minute mark the velocity is $v$. By the intermediate value theorem, the velocity changes direction at some point between $0$ and $10$ minutes. This is the most that can be said for certain about what happens.

Comment: Well, "the velocity function must be continuous" until one hits a brick wall; beyond that I will only surmise.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Even if it hits a brick wall it's still continuous :) Walls don't exert an infinite force. Velocity will always be continuous.

Comment: It's a joke! Check out the education on my profile.

Comment: @Ataraxia: Using intermediate value theorem, and traveling assumptions (v -> 1.1v -> -v) there is some point which the object must stop! but as "André Nicolas" said above; it is not necessarily the case.